# Select from a select result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select SQL query on Mysql that returns a result in the form with two columns:

```
number  date
1       date1
1       date2
2       date3
.
.
```

How do you i select from the select query and keep only the most recent date for each number.

I have problems working the query result.

Comment: @e4c5 you aren't guaranteed to get the most recent one when you do that, and you'd only show one result in total

Comment: Tip of today: Do a `GROUP BY`, use `MAX()` to get each number's latest date.

Comment: And hope your `date` is of `DATE` datatype, not a string. Othewise convert it to DATE before aggregating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your query as a derived table.  Since you didn't provide your query, let's use this for example:

```
SELECT Name, Date
FROM   YourQuery
```

Now take `MAX(Date)` and `GROUP BY Name` with your query as the derived table:

```
SELECT MAX(Date), Name
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Date
    FROM   YourQuery
     ) a
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Because he said those results are the result of a query... Since we can't see the query, I'm assuming it isn't a straight pull from a single table.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough! Derived table is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the number and date, you can do a regular group by on the returned select and it should do the trick:

```
select 
   a.number, 
   max(a.date) from 
(select number, date from table_name ) a
group by a.number
```

If you have other columns that you would like to show on that row with the most recent date, this should do the trick:

```
select 
  a.number, 
  a.lastentrytime,
  b.some_other_column
from (
       select number, 
       max(date) recent_date
 from table_name group by number) a 
inner join table_name b on a.number= b.number and a.recent_date= b.date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as ( 
select number, row_number() over(order by date desc) as rn from thistable ) 
select number from cte where rn=1
```

You can use this query to get most recent record.